# Sockets - Packet Sending Exception

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, ip, packets

I've written the following code:

```
byte[] packetdata = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("<hello world>");
            string ip = "000.000.000.000";
            int port = 80;
            IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);
            Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            client.SendTimeout = 1;
            while (true) client.SendTo(packetdata, ep);
```

I've tried entering the IP addresses of multiple computers (testing purposes), and every time, an Exception is thrown after a few seconds.

The exception:

```
SocketException was unhandled: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

What does it mean? That the computer's IP is protected from network stressing attacks?
Or is it just a code error?

Comment: Did you see if the Windows firewall was running on the target computers?  Do you have a server running on those remote targets on port 80?  Are they expecting the kind of message you're sending?

Comment: Timeout generally will mean: a) no server listening on port 80 on the target, or (b) firewall on computer blocking inbound traffic to that port.

Comment: If there is no server listening for connections, or the message can't get there (firewall etc), then this is what happens. Does the target machine have a running server on that port?

Comment: Thanks, but the target computers are just Windows computers with firewalls turned on, but no port 80 server. Is there a general port that can be used to send packets to any computer? This is needed for stress testing. I didn't make a server on these computers, they're totally normal.

Comment: What kind of stress testing are you trying to perform?

Comment: Stress testing for DoS/DDoS protection.

Comment: @BkueRay then they already passed the test by ignoring you :) a [D]DoS attack is executed against either a server or the network infrastructure... I'm not quite sure what you think you are targeting here...